# Can we define a variable inside a Jenkins parameterized build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My scenario is, I have parameterized build and inside the build section, I have executed shell where I define a variable and then echo to print it. But it doesn't print anything in the console output.

I hope I have made myself clear. Could anyone please answer my question?

```
current_folder=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`
echo $current_folder
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNYim.png)

Comment: Are you trying to show the value of the parameter (set when the Jenkins job is initiated), or show the value of a locally defined variable (unrelated to the parameter?). Can you add your code that isn't working?

Comment: `echo $PARAMETER_NAME`

Comment: It's the value of the locally defined variable. Here is my piece of code inside the execute shell
current_folder=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`

#__timestamp=$(date +%d%m%Y-%H%M) --date '2 hours';

#__packageName=ibm+${__timestamp}

echo $current_folder

Comment: Can you put your full example code in the question and not just in your comment (you've given different examples).  Regardless, the simple example should work - see my answer below.

Comment: Can you also add the console output, it must show something about starting/finishing - see answer below.

Comment: See this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557) about not posting images, it's better to add the console output as formatted text. The image does show that you are getting a date value to console, so it's working for the locally defined variable. It's hard to understand what your problem is, I've updated my answer to reference a build parameter - which is no different. Can you add more detail about the exact nature of your problem if it remains?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Jenkins ver. 2.32.3** and a simple freestyle job, running on mac OS, using an execute shell build step of:

```
current_folder=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`
echo $current_folder
```

Gives output of:

```
$ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/kh/4fl0eeldofefmmsfd/T/hudson89388543547899686.sh
++ date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S
+ current_folder=20180613-081712
+ echo 20180613-081712
20180613-081712
Finished: SUCCESS
```

In a similar fashion, setting the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
current_folder=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`
echo $current_folder
```

Gives:

```
$ /bin/bash /var/folders/kh/by0kd93dfew5fgjhy000h6/T/hudson62702345565786787.sh
20180613-081655
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The same applies to a parameter that is defined as part of the Jenkins job, underneath the
`This project is parameterized` checkbox once set. For example, if you have a string parameter called `userName` with a default value of `User1`, then you can print it's value in an `Execute Shell` build step using:

```
echo $userName
echo ${userName}
echo "In a string ${userName}"
```

Giving:

```
User1
User1
In a string User1
```

Comment: yes, I am fine with this. But my problem is that I have some parameters defined for my project. Now, can I do the same thing in the execute shell for a parameterized project?

Comment: I have added the console o/p in the question.